# TypeLoadException, MissingMethodException

Tags: android, json, mono

I'm working on an Android app, and am using the Newtonian.Json libray for deserializing some Json returned from a website. I was able to do a mock up of this using windows, but now working on the Android version, I can't get the Netwonian library to work, I'm getting the TypeLoadException, and MissingMethodException, which normally tells me I've referenced the wrong version library for my framework. Well, I'm building the app using .Net 4.0, and I've made sure to use the Newtonian.Json library that is for .Net 4.0, so now I'm stuck. Has anyone else had problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling for android, you shouldn't use a precompiled version for the desktop.

The best thing is to just use the component from the component store: http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/.

Alternatively, you could compile the sources yourself in an android project and reference that.

Comment: Im using an older Mono, not Xamarin, so no component store. I'll try the source compile and see if that helps. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Don't know what the deal was, I just redid my app on the .net 4.5 framework, and the Json .dll reference worked just fine. Not sure why it wasn't working on the 4.0 framework.